# UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum generates error implicit declaration of function, why?

Tags: iphone

In my project I am trying to save video to the iPhone after being taken by the camera.

When I call the method:

UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)

It reports the error:

Implicit declaration of function 'UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum'

I've imported MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h

I was previously using this same code for saving camera pictures, and it worked fine.

In another class, in the same project, I am able to reference the UIKit method:

UIImagePNGRepresentation()

without any problems

So why does it give me this error?

Comment: It's strange, because I also have UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() in the other delegate method, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two hours of hunting I finally realized my project was set up for OS 3.0, and thus, the method was unavailable.  It needed to be set for 3.1